# Why cannot I insert rows longer than 65521 from Cloud Functions to BigQuery table via Pub/Sub and Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

To learn more about Cloud Functions, I decided to implement a scraping script. The function loadds the https://www.bbc.com/, encodes it using base64, then publishes the result to a Pub/Sub topic. A Dataflow job is subscribed to this topic, and streams the messages to BigQuery. Interestingly, messages longer than 65521 do not arrive.

My cloud function:

```
def hello_pubsub(event, context):

    import re
    import json
    import base64
    import requests
    import bs4 as bs
    from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

    def publish(message):
        project_id = "adventdalen"
        topic_name = "scrape"
        publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
        topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)
        future = publisher.publish(
            topic_path, data=message.encode('utf-8')
        )


    url = "https://www.bbc.com/"
    page = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'})
    bspage = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    decoded = base64.b64encode(bspage.encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')
    print(decoded)

    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:100]})) # <- this makes into bigquery
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:1000]})) # <- this makes into bigquery
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:20000]})) # <- this makes into bigquery
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:40000]})) # <- this makes into bigquery
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:60000]})) # <- this makes into bigquery

    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:62000]})) # <- this makes into bigquery
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:64000]})) # <- this makes into bigquery
    
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:64800]})) # <- this makes into bigquery
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:64900]})) # <- this makes into bigquery
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:65000]})) # <- this makes into bigquery
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:65100]})) # <- this makes into bigquery
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:65200]})) # <- this makes into bigquery
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:65500]})) # <- this makes into bigquery
    
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:65520]})) # <- this makes into bigquery

    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:65521]})) # <- this makes into bigquery
    
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:65522]})) # <- this does not
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:65524]})) # <- this does not
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:65528]})) # <- this does not
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:65532]})) # <- this does not
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:65536]})) # <- this does not


    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:65540]})) # <- this does not
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:65560]})) # <- this does not
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:65580]})) # <- this does not
    
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:65600]})) # <- this does not
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:65700]})) # <- this does not
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:65800]})) # <- this does not
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:65900]})) # <- this does not
    
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:66000]})) # <- this does not
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:68000]})) # <- this does not
        
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:70000]})) # <- this does not
    publish(json.dumps({"html":decoded[:90000]})) # <- this does not
```

I check rows in my BigQuery table, and the longest row is 65521.

What am I doing wrong? I haven't found any quota limit which would explain this observation. (I also checked `decoded`, that string is around 280k long, so definitely long enough to have longer rows in BQ than 65521.)

Comment: Is the message correctly published to PubSub? If so, what your Dataflow do? What the code? the processing? Can you share more detail? There is several steps between your function and BigQuery, all the hop must be checked.

Comment: As Guillaume said, could you provide more details?